# Existence of Immersion of a manifold in Euclidean space?

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to prove the following claim which I saw in some paper:

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth, oriented, simply connected manifold, which is homeomorphic to a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Then, there exists an orientation-preserving smooth immersion $f:M\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

**Remarks:**

1) The dimensions of the domain and co-domain are the same, therefore any such $f$ will be in particular a local diffeomorphism.

2) Since $M$ is conected every local diffeomorphism is orientation preserving or orientaton-reversing. Hence, it is enough to find an immersion and then compose it with any orientation reversing diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if necessary.

3) I think some of the above conditions on $M$ are unnecessary for this to hold (they seem unnatural to me, and are related to other aspects of the paper).

Comment: I think it will be helpful to try to answer the question with as few assumptions as possible on $M$. What happens in the case where we only assume $M$ is an $n$-dimensional smooth manifold? Can we immerse  every $n$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No. You are surely going to need many of those assumptions. You cannot immerse a closed $n$-manifold into $\Bbb R^n$ (local diffeomorphism implies open, compact implies image is closed, your manifold is not all of $\Bbb R^n$. There is a result of Gromov that says every open parallelizable $n$-manifold immerses in $\Bbb R^n$ but it is going to be harder than whatever is intended here.